# Buffer to flush either when a specified time elapses or a count is reached

Tags: c#

I have a system that will be sending telemetry or events to a DB table and I want to limit how many HTTP connections it opens to my server but at the same time I don't want the events accumulating and sitting on the client machine for too long.  For example I could get a burst of events or I could get one event and not get anymore for a long time.

I tried using Rx to do this with its Buffer extension method but I didn't like the way it behaved.  It would notify me with empty lists, so I wrote the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (TelemetryBuffer<int> telemetryBuffer = new TelemetryBuffer<int>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 5))
        {
            telemetryBuffer.Subscribe(
                delegate (List<int> items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(items.Count);
                });

            Random random = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                int item = (int)(random.NextDouble()*1000);
                Thread.Sleep(item);
                telemetryBuffer.OnNext(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

class TelemetryBuffer<T> : IObservable<List<T>>, IObserver<T>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _syncObject = new object();
    private readonly List<IObserver<List<T>>> _observers = new List<IObserver<List<T>>>();
    private readonly List<T> _items = new List<T>();
    private Timer _timer;

    private readonly TimeSpan _bufferTimeSpan;
    private readonly int _bufferSize;

    public TelemetryBuffer(TimeSpan bufferTimeSpan, int bufferSize)
    {
        _bufferTimeSpan = bufferTimeSpan;
        _bufferSize = bufferSize;
    }

    public void OnNext(T item)
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            _items.Add(item);
            if (_timer == null)
            {
                _timer = new Timer(OnTick, null, _bufferTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
            }
            else if (_items.Count >= _bufferSize)
            {
                foreach (IObserver<List<T>> observer in _observers)
                {
                    observer.OnNext(new List<T>(_items));
                }
                if (_timer != null)
                {
                    _timer.Dispose();
                    _timer = null;
                }
                _items.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTick(object state)
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            if (_timer != null)
            {
                foreach (IObserver<List<T>> observer in _observers)
                {
                    observer.OnNext(new List<T>(_items));
                }
                _timer.Dispose();
                _timer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnError(Exception ex)
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            foreach (IObserver<List<T>> observer in _observers)
            {
                observer.OnError(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            foreach (IObserver<List<T>> observer in _observers)
            {
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }
        }
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<List<T>> observer)
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            _observers.Add(observer);
            return new Subscription(this, observer);
        }
    }

    private void Unsubscribe(IObserver<List<T>> observer)
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            _observers.Remove(observer);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            foreach (IObserver<List<T>> observer in _observers)
            {
                observer.OnNext(_items);
            }
            if (_timer != null)
            {
                _timer.Dispose();
                _timer = null;
            }
            _items.Clear();
        }
    }

    class Subscription : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TelemetryBuffer<T> _telemetryBuffer;
        private readonly IObserver<List<T>> _observer;

        public Subscription(TelemetryBuffer<T> telemetryBuffer, IObserver<List<T>> observer)
        {
            _telemetryBuffer = telemetryBuffer;
            _observer = observer;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _telemetryBuffer.Unsubscribe(_observer);
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think of it?  The code doesn't have to be super performant, in the wild I will have values something like 30-60 seconds and 25-100 buffer size expecting in most situations to get on average an event per second with it sometimes getting large spikes up to 100 per second, depending on the event type with each event type getting its own buffer(limited to 6 event types).

Comment: Were there other problems you had with `Buffer`? If the only problem was empty lists, you could use `.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 5).Where(buffer => buffer.Any())`

Comment: It wasn't just the empty buffer part it is more that the timer, the 5 seconds starts on creation and ticks every 5 seconds, so if I had nothing for 4 seconds, then I got 1 event, the tick at 5 would upload that 1 event, I want the timer to start when the event is delivered.  Also with buffer I was using a BlockingCollection which mean I needed a thread dedicated to the subscription and it was complex to stop listening.

Comment: Are the buffers emitted by `TelemetryBuffer` meant to be non-overlapping? e.g. if I have `var telemetryBuffer = new TelemetryBuffer<long>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10)` and I send it the values 0, 1, 2, ... each second (`Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(x => telemetryBuffer.OnNext(x));`, the buffers should be { 0 .. 4 }, { 5 .. 9 }, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Looks pretty good. A few years back I wrote [something similar](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66918/buffering-of-fast-changing-datapoints-or-events) but it doesn't handle multiple subscribers (just a single callback). Gives me a few ideas on how to refactor that stuff.

A few minors:

1. I'd prefer `Enqueue` or `Put` instead of `OnNext` as the name. Somehow seems semantically more appropriate.
2. Shouldn't `_items` be cleared in `OnTick` or else you will report the same data twice?
3. This code is essentially repeated three times:

   > ```
   >     foreach (IObserver<List<T>> observer in _observers)
   >     {
   >         observer.OnNext(_items);
   >     }
   >     if (_timer != null)
   >     {
   >         _timer.Dispose();
   >         _timer = null;
   >     }
   >     _items.Clear();
   > ```

   It should be extracted into a method.